# Would moving quarks constitute a current?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics

I know that it would take an almost infinite amount of energy to isolate quarks, but let's say we've gotten past that and we have isolated quarks and put them in motion. Would that be a current since they have a non-zero charge?

Also, I may be taking quite a leap here but there's also this: each particle would have less kinetic energy than say, an electron (which usually carries current in a metal). Because $ E_k = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 $, assuming the quarks are moving significantly slower than $c$ (just like electrons in a wire) and $m_e >> m_q$. So with less kinetic energy, would this current generally produce less heat?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to "ignore" confinement. It's not a matter of having enough energy.

Comment: Quark masses are actually larger than the electron mass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quarks are charged, so the only possible answer is "yes".

Nor do you have to isolate quarks to test this. By choosing Baryons whose valence content consists entirely of a single type of quark, we can get those in motion and look to see if they are a current.

So we choose a $\Delta^{++}$ (valence content $uuu$), a $\Delta^-$ (valence content $ddd$), or a $\Omega^-$ (valence content $sss$) and send them pass the induction sense wires of a TPC (for instance). Now, we can't make dedicated beams of these particles, but the fact that we detect them in detectors that work because of their electromagnetic properties is enough.

To do the heavier quarks is harder (and the top can't be treated this way at all because it decays before it can hadronize), but the principle is the same.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you. Any thoughts on the kinetic energy? @dmckee